# Get maximum value in dictionary for a given tuple key where elements of the tuple may be in different positions

Tags: python

I have the following dictionary:

```
{('2019-07-243541760601284691', '2019-07-243541760603812661'): 1086,
('2019-07-243541760601314711', '2019-07-243541760603996721'): 662,
('2019-07-243541760603794841', '2019-07-243541760600899921'): 483,
('2019-07-243541760603794841', '2019-07-243541760601224211'): 70,
('2019-07-243541760603794841', '2019-07-243541760607368321'): 54,
('2019-07-243541760600899921', '2019-07-243541760601224211'): 93,
('2019-07-243541760600899921', '2019-07-243541760607368321'): 74,
('2019-07-243541760601224211', '2019-07-243541760607368321'): 490,
('2019-07-243541760613553761', '2019-07-243541760602348611'): 484,
('2019-07-243541760602450401', '2019-07-243541760602927941'): 1118,
('2019-07-243541760603292161', '2019-07-243541760606108621'): 732}
```

The keys are tuples of unique ids. As you can see certain ids are repeated within both columns (eg. lines 3 to 5 have the same first id, and element 2 from line 3 is also present in lines 6 and 7). I want to find a way to return the maximum value for each given unique id.

If it helps the output I am looking for would look like this:

```
{('2019-07-243541760601284691', '2019-07-243541760603812661'): 1086,
('2019-07-243541760601314711', '2019-07-243541760603996721'): 662,
('2019-07-243541760603794841', '2019-07-243541760600899921'): 483,
('2019-07-243541760601224211', '2019-07-243541760607368321'): 490,
('2019-07-243541760613553761', '2019-07-243541760602348611'): 484,
('2019-07-243541760602450401', '2019-07-243541760602927941'): 1118,
('2019-07-243541760603292161', '2019-07-243541760606108621'): 732}
```

In other words each unique id should appear **at most** in one key in the dictionary.

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I `sort` by values in a list `L`. Then I iterate over `L`, and I store each new tuple's id in a set `ids_set`, and if they were not in this set yet, then I put them into my dict `final`.

```
d = {('2019-07-243541760601284691', '2019-07-243541760603812661'): 1086,
('2019-07-243541760601314711', '2019-07-243541760603996721'): 662,
('2019-07-243541760603794841', '2019-07-243541760600899921'): 483,
('2019-07-243541760603794841', '2019-07-243541760601224211'): 70,
('2019-07-243541760603794841', '2019-07-243541760607368321'): 54,
('2019-07-243541760600899921', '2019-07-243541760601224211'): 93,
('2019-07-243541760600899921', '2019-07-243541760607368321'): 74,
('2019-07-243541760601224211', '2019-07-243541760607368321'): 490,
('2019-07-243541760613553761', '2019-07-243541760602348611'): 484,
('2019-07-243541760602450401', '2019-07-243541760602927941'): 1118,
('2019-07-243541760603292161', '2019-07-243541760606108621'): 732}

L = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)
# L = [(('2019-07-243541760602450401', '2019-07-243541760602927941'), 1118),...

final = {}
ids_set = set()
for i in L:
    t = i[0] # tuple
    val = i[1]
    if (t[0] or t[1]) not in ids_set:
        ids_set.update(t)
        final[t] = val

for i, v in final.items():
    print(i, v)
```

Output :

```
('2019-07-243541760602450401', '2019-07-243541760602927941') 1118
('2019-07-243541760601284691', '2019-07-243541760603812661') 1086
('2019-07-243541760603292161', '2019-07-243541760606108621') 732
('2019-07-243541760601314711', '2019-07-243541760603996721') 662
('2019-07-243541760601224211', '2019-07-243541760607368321') 490
('2019-07-243541760613553761', '2019-07-243541760602348611') 484
('2019-07-243541760603794841', '2019-07-243541760600899921') 483
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the behavior of the built in types in Python. For your case it's really easy to create a dict subclass that will store duplicated values in lists under the same key automatically. You can then get the max value of the list.

```
class Dictlist(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        try:
            self[key]
        except KeyError:
            super(Dictlist, self).__setitem__(key, [])
        self[key].append(value)
```

Output example:

```
>>> d = dictlist.Dictlist()
>>> d['test'] = 1
>>> d['test'] = 2
>>> d['test'] = 3
>>> d
{'test': [1, 2, 3]}
>>> d['other'] = 100
>>> d
{'test': [1, 2, 3], 'other': [100]}
```

So when you want to return the max value of a key, just pass the key as the parameters and this will give you the max value in that list.

`max(dict[key_value])`

Comment: Sorry if I've misunderstood your response (or didn't make it clear in the question) but each of the keys is unique so wouldn't I still end up with a single value for each key doing it this way?

Comment: I see. so what you can do is to use the first element of the tuple as the key and then find the max element of that list. You can then construct another dictionary where the key matches the key of the max element. I can elaborate on this method if you are interested. The other answer should be sufficient for your problem

Answer (score 0):

```py
d = {('2019-07-243541760601284691', '2019-07-243541760603812661'): 1086,
('2019-07-243541760601314711', '2019-07-243541760603996721'): 662,
('2019-07-243541760603794841', '2019-07-243541760600899921'): 483,
('2019-07-243541760603794841', '2019-07-243541760601224211'): 70,
('2019-07-243541760603794841', '2019-07-243541760607368321'): 54,
('2019-07-243541760600899921', '2019-07-243541760601224211'): 93,
('2019-07-243541760600899921', '2019-07-243541760607368321'): 74,
('2019-07-243541760601224211', '2019-07-243541760607368321'): 490,
('2019-07-243541760613553761', '2019-07-243541760602348611'): 484,
('2019-07-243541760602450401', '2019-07-243541760602927941'): 1118,
('2019-07-243541760603292161', '2019-07-243541760606108621'): 732}

# flatten the dict so that each id in the tuple has value
# but first make sure we sort on values so that if the key appears twice
# the latest element should be the one with max value (dict only keeps one item per key)
sorted_dict = dict(item for item in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[-1]))
flat_dict = {**{k[0]:v for k,v in d.items()}, **{k[1]:v for k,v in sorted_dict .items()}}

# get the unique keys you want
keys, already_used = [], []
for k in d:
    if k[0] in already_used or k[1] in already_used:
        continue
    keys.append(k)
    already_used.extend(k)

# now create the new_dict
new_dict = {k:max(flat_dict[k[0]], flat_dict[k[1]]) for k in keys}
```

Output

```py
>>> new_dict
{('2019-07-243541760601284691', '2019-07-243541760603812661'): 1086,
 ('2019-07-243541760601314711', '2019-07-243541760603996721'): 662,
 ('2019-07-243541760603794841', '2019-07-243541760600899921'): 483,
 ('2019-07-243541760601224211', '2019-07-243541760607368321'): 490,
 ('2019-07-243541760613553761', '2019-07-243541760602348611'): 484,
 ('2019-07-243541760602450401', '2019-07-243541760602927941'): 1118,
 ('2019-07-243541760603292161', '2019-07-243541760606108621'): 732}
```